# how to right way in call webservice with json and without json in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, json, web-services

i have included this two way of webservice but i have not sure this way are right or worng

**1)With json**

```
//create two class variable
NSMutableData *receivedData;
NSURLConnection *firstConnection;


NSMutableDictionary *userData=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
//Add some data in userData
NSDictionary *sendData=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:userData forKey:@"data"];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:sendData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSString *urlString=@"www.example.com/user_register.php";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody:jsonData];

receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
firstConnection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
if(!firstConnection){
    receivedData=nil;
}
```

after i have created three method to handle request

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
     // get response code
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    //get a response data
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // if connection fail 
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSError *errorJson=nil;
    //received data to convert disctionary
    NSMutableDictionary *dataDistionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&errorJson];
}
```

i have perfectly received server data

**2) without json**

```
NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.example.com/get_hotels.php?city_id=%d",cityID];
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
theConnection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:myRequest delegate:self];
if(!theConnection){
    receivedData=nil;
}



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
     // get response code
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    //get a response data
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // if connection fail 
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSError *errorJson=nil;
    //received data to convert disctionary
    NSMutableDictionary *dataDistionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&errorJson];
}
```

they are two way are perfectly work but any other way to json parsing i have no idea so please can help us

Comment: give AFNetworking a look. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking . the most powerful networking library used by lot of apps

Comment: @file_get_contents('php://input');